# Magento rendering submenu too far down

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, magento

New enough to Magento and trying to figure out what is going on I have moved my top level menu up to be level with other items in the header but when I hover over it to see sub categories they are still being rendered in the original location.

I enabled Template path hints to try find where this was being rendered from and found `\vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html\topmenu.phtml` but cannot figure out where this is being rendered from.

I think it might be somewhere in the Javascript but cannot find the location. Any help to get rid of these pesky 47px would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is your theme really called *module-theme*? What does it extend? It's quite possible (Magento 1.9) that the CSS could come from about 4 different locations depending on the theme you're extending... though that appears to be inline looking at your inspector image?

Comment: No if I was overwriting any files they'd be in app\design\frontend\Magento\Lifting365 instead am using magento 2.1.11 haven't overwritten anything in the menu system at all just moved the top level of the menu up via css but cannot do the same for the submenu because its being rendered with its own inline style

Comment: Ah sorry - should have clocked it was Magento 2 from the directory structure...